# How to notify all observers without holding the thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, observers

I have a thread inside a class like this-

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class Download extends Observable {

    private int state = 0;
    private final Thread myThread = new Thread(() -> {
        /*
         some work to do here
         */
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(state);
    });

    public void download(int state) {
        if (!myThread.isAlive()) {
            this.state = state;
            myThread.start();
        }
    }

    public Thread getThread() {
        return myThread;
    }

    public static void MyMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        Download down = new Download();
        down.addObserver((Observable ob, Object dat) -> {
            System.out.println(ob);
            if ((int) dat == 1) {
                down.download(2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("success");
            }
        });
        down.download(1);
        down.getThread().join();
    }

    public static void main() throws InterruptedException {
        MyMethod();
    }
}
```

The problem is I never get it to print the `"success"` message.

I assume, it is because all observers are being notified from inside of `MyThread`. So when `down.download(2)` is called from the observer inside `MyMethod()`, the previous thread is still running and the call is ignored.

How can I notify all observers from the main thread, not from the `myThread`?

Comment: `if(dat == 1)` : This compares object-references. You want to compare primitive int instead.

Comment: @MarkusKull Actually it doesn't do anything except cause a compile-time error. This is what happens when people don't post the actual code they're using.

Comment: @Kayaman You got it right. Sorry I could not post my full code because it is too big. I wrote this demo version without compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `down.download(2)` from within the execution of `MyThread`, therefore the thread is still alive which means that your download method does nothing because of `if(!myThread.isAlive())`.

I would recommend you to use the [Executor framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and [Listenable Futures from Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) instead of creating threads manually. Example code from the Guava wiki:

```
ListeningExecutorService service = 
    MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
ListenableFuture<Explosion> explosion = service.submit(new Callable<Explosion>() {
  public Explosion call() {
    return pushBigRedButton();
  }
});
Futures.addCallback(explosion, new FutureCallback<Explosion>() {
  // we want this handler to run immediately after we push the big red button!
  public void onSuccess(Explosion explosion) {
    walkAwayFrom(explosion);
  }
  public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
    battleArchNemesis(); // escaped the explosion!
  }
});
```

Note that [Futures.addCallback(..)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor)) also has an overload which allows you to determine which executor should execute the callback, this seems to be what you want.

Comment: I did not know about this framework I guess I should start learning. Thanks.

Comment: Note also that Java 8 has the [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) which is equivalent to Guava's `ListenableFuture`.